# AS3 child MovieClip unresponsive to startDrag()

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, mouseevent, draggable

### Background

Let me give a little background on the problem. I'm creating a custom video player with video controls at the bottom. Set up like so:

```
 _________________
| video container |
|  _____________  |
| |    video    | |
| |             | |
| |             | |
| |_____________| |
| |  controls   | |
| |_____________| |
|_________________|
```

### The Platform

- Adobe AIR 3.2
- Flash Player 11.2

### The Problem

The controls are the typical controls you'd expect: play, pause, volume, etc. The issue I'm having is with dragging a volume slider inside the controls container. The volume control is composed of a track with a child sprite object. When I hook up the event listener for dragging it is completely unresponsive to being dragged. The code:

```js
private function make_slider_track():Sprite {
  var track:Sprite = graphics_util.make_box_sprite(btn_bg_up, vol_slider_width, 1);

  var knob:MovieClip = make_slider_knob();
  knob.y = -(vol_knob_height)/2+1;
  track.addChild(knob);

  var volume_drag:Function = function(e:MouseEvent) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    // add events
    knob.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, volume_stop_drag);
    knob.startDrag();
  };

  var volume_stop_drag:Function = function(e:MouseEvent) {
    // remove events
    knob.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, volume_stop_drag);
    knob.stopDrag();
  };
  knob.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, volume_drag, true);

  return track;
}
```

After the code returns the track I immediately add it as a child of the controls container.

The behavior I'm seeing is that when I click the knob to drag it (I removed the bounding rect I had for testing for any movement whatsoever) is that it will fire the mouse down callback and (I assume) the startDrag call but I'll move the mouse and the knob sprite stays in place.

I'm completely at a loss as to what's happening here so any insight would be helpful.

### UPDATE

It seems the issue is related to tweening the video container. I'm using caurina.transitions.Tweener. What am I doing wrong here? And how has nobody ever had this issue? Here's how I'm issuing the tween:

```
player.rotationX = -90;
Tweener.addTween(player, { rotationX:0, x:to_x, y:to_y, alpha:1, time:0.5 } );
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is with the 3rd param of your `knob.addEventListener()` , the `useCapture` param, which is set to `true` in your code and according to Adobe, the [`useCapture`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#addEventListener())

> Determines whether the listener works in the capture phase or the target and bubbling phases. If useCapture is set to true, the listener processes the event only during the capture phase and not in the target or bubbling phase. If useCapture is false, the listener processes the event only during the target or bubbling phase. To listen for the event in all three phases, call addEventListener twice, once with useCapture set to true, then again with useCapture set to false.

So in your case, the listener works only in the capture phase which concern only the parent object of your target one, and that's why your dragging is not working.

So to get your code working with `useCapture` as true, you should attach the event listener to your target parent object :

```
knob.parent.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, volume_drag, true);
```

Or simply, remove the `useCapture` param ( equivalent to set it to `false` ) :

```
knob.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, volume_drag);
```

Don't forget the `MOUSE_UP` event also.

For more details about using events, take a look on :

- [Event listeners](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e54.html).
- [Introduction to event handling in ActionScript 3.0](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/event_handling_as3.html).
- [The event flow](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e4f.html).
- [Event capture and bubbling](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS948100b6829bd5a67edfb831266c0b5fc6-8000.html).

Hope that can help.

Comment: I did try with/without the capture flag. It didn't seem to affect the behavior. It definitely had to do with how the video player was tweened. Once I removed the tween drag worked exactly as expected.

Comment: @cdacamara I tried to answer according to your available code and information ... the most important that your have resolved your problem.

Comment: Absolutely, and that's not something you could have known. I appreciate the answer and it actually did give me a little bit more insight as to when I should be using the useCapture flag. It wasn't until I got fed up with trying things that I eventually tried removing the tween animation. I had no idea that tweening could impact interactive objects inside a container.